# Check if specific method has been called when calling static method

Tags: c#, attributes

I'm in search of an easy mechanism to check if `Initialize()` has been called whenever another method is called.

Here's an example

```
private static string _serviceUrl;

private static Service _service;

public ServiceHelper()
{

}

public static void Initialize(string serviceUrl)
{
     _serviceUrl = serviceUrl;
     _service = new Service(_serviceUrl);
}

public static Foo()
{

}

public static Foo2()
{

}
```

Now what I want is sth. to check in `Foo / Foo2` that `_service != null` (assert `Initialize()` has been called - otherwise throw Exception)

Since I need to check that in EVERY method I thought there must be sth easier than checking it with `if` inside of every method.

(Sadly) i'm not that deep into `Attributes` - may this be an approach ?

Pseudo Code:

```
[AssertInitialized]
public static void Foo()
{

}
```

Comment: Set a flag `initialized` and check that in your static methods

Comment: @BiesiGrr "Since I need to check that in EVERY method I thought there must be sth easier than checking it with if inside of every method."

Comment: Might a singleton help in that case? You could have a static instance of it in your class and initialize it with a constructor.

Comment: Note that you wouldn't really be saving any time by marking all your methods with `[AssertInitialized]` (assuming it existed) rather than calling `CheckInitialized()` inside

Comment: @KevinGosse what is best-practice for scenarios like this ?

Comment: Using a singleton, as suggested by @BiesiGrr, sounds like a good idea. Make a class with a private constructor, a static `Initialize` method, and a static `Instance` property. Throw an exception in the getter of the property if `Initialize` hasn't been called. Use it like this: `YourClass.Instance.Foo()`

Comment: Note that using a singleton has issues of its own (especially for testability), but those are issues you'd have with your current code anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a wrapper-property that throws an error if the backing field is not initialize:

```
private static Service _service;
private static Service Service
{
    get
    {
        if(_service == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Need to call Initialize(string) first");
        }
        return _service;
    }
}
```

or in C#7

```
private static Service _service;
private static Service Service => _service ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Need to call Initialize(string) first");
```

Then in code call `Service` instead of `_service`. This ensures that `Service` **must** be initialized if you try to call it.